# nuxt page switch components change css text color and url path

Tags: css, url, nuxt.js

i have a page that able to switch component between login and register.

1. how do i make the text show black after selected it and switch back and fore ?
   sample like this :
   **https://softauthor.com/toggle-button-in-vue-js/**
   [image]

[image]

2. i need each component to change page url too, the order will be like this.

clicked on login = http://localhost:3000/login

clicked on register = http://localhost:3000/register

```
<template>
<div>
                      <div class="ps-page__content">
                <div class="ps-tab-root">

                    <div class="ps-form--auth">
                        <ul class="ps-tab-list">
                            <li v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab">
                                <a @click="selected = tab">
                                    {{tab}}
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <component :is="selected"></component>


                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end Account Content -->

</div>
</template>

<script>
    import Login from '@/components/MyAccountLogin.vue'
    import Register from '@/components/MyAccountRegister.vue'
   
    export default {
       components: {
         Login,
         Register
       },
       data() {
            return {
                tabs: ["Login", "Register"],
                selected: "Login"
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

here is the sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-zuq4pe?file=pages%2Findex.vue

Comment: The component can't update the URL without the page changing. If you want the URL to update, you should put the login and register components in separate pages and set it up that way.

Comment: @alexScott Yeah i hope do it without setting up like that, but instead switch able to change the url too, but seem like unlikely now.